# Installing bluefish editor on OSX lion

Tags: osx-lion, bluefish

I downloaded the blue from [here](http://bluefish.mrball.net/stable/binaries/macosx/). I download the last file .dmg and installed it on OSX Lion. Installation went ok. But it crashes every time I start it.

Is `bluefish 2.0.3.dmg` compatible with OSX Lion? I found another link that talks about installing it on Mac OS X [here](http://bfwiki.tellefsen.net/index.php/Installing_Bluefish#Installing_Bluefish_on_Mac_OS_X) but I dont really get it. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: The link you gave says that bluefish's dmg installation method crashes on Lion. Maybe you could try the Macports instructions.

Comment: I see noticed it.

Comment: [It isn't.](http://roaringapps.com/app:4188) That site is great for Lion compatibility. 'Twas also the first result on Google ;-).